# Infinity loop in recursive sql query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, infinite-loop, recursive-cte

Maybe someone will advise me on how to solve my problem.
I have no idea why it happens and how to solve it.
In my opinion the reason that my sql code is not working
is that it becomes to infinitive loop.
I have table:

```
CREATE TABLE `c_logistics_tran_group3` (
  `ltrgr_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ltrgr_lagr_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ltrgr_ltran_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ltrgr_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `c_logistics_tran_group3`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ltrgr_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `ltrgr_lagr_id` (`ltrgr_lagr_id`,`ltrgr_ltran_id`),
  ADD KEY `c_logistics_tran_group3_ibfk_2` (`ltrgr_ltran_id`);

ALTER TABLE `c_logistics_tran_group3`
  MODIFY `ltrgr_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

and data:

```
INSERT INTO `c_logistics_tran_group3` 
(`ltrgr_id`, `ltrgr_lagr_id`, `ltrgr_ltran_id`, `ltrgr_created`) 
VALUES
(2373, 2154, 2312, '2021-09-09 07:54:55'),
(2378, 2154, 2314, '2021-09-09 08:05:25'),
(2382, 2154, 2318, '2021-09-09 10:37:37'),
(2450, 2154, 2386, '2021-09-17 11:44:58'),
(2375, 2156, 2312, '2021-09-09 07:57:14'),
(2380, 2156, 2316, '2021-09-09 10:25:01'),
(2381, 2156, 2317, '2021-09-09 10:37:07'),
(2451, 2156, 2387, '2021-09-17 11:45:37'),
(2376, 2157, 2312, '2021-09-09 08:03:10'),
(2387, 2157, 2323, '2021-09-10 10:36:15'),
(2388, 2157, 2324, '2021-09-10 10:42:59'),
(2449, 2157, 2385, '2021-09-17 11:41:36'),
(2377, 2158, 2312, '2021-09-09 08:04:35');
COMMIT;
```

my sql code:

```
with
  recursive 
      edges as (
          select t1.ltrgr_lagr_id as lagr_id1, t2.ltrgr_lagr_id as lagr_id2
          from c_logistics_tran_group3 t1 
          inner join c_logistics_tran_group3 t2 on t2.ltrgr_ltran_id = t1.ltrgr_ltran_id
          where 1 = 1
          and t1.ltrgr_lagr_id in(2154, 2156, 2157, 2158) 
          and t2.ltrgr_lagr_id in(2154, 2156, 2157, 2158)
      ),
      cte as (
          select lagr_id1, lagr_id2, concat(lagr_id1, ',', lagr_id2) as visited
          from edges
          union all
          select c.lagr_id1, e.lagr_id2, concat(c.visited, ',', e.lagr_id2)
          from cte c
          inner join edges e on e.lagr_id1 = c.lagr_id2
          where not find_in_set(e.lagr_id2, c.visited)
      )
select * from cte;
```

This SQL code performs the task described here:
[Select keys connected by its values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65097582/select-keys-connected-by-its-values)

If I remove from the list any lagr_id every thing works fine. For eg.:

```
          and t1.ltrgr_lagr_id in(2154, 2156, 2157) 
          and t2.ltrgr_lagr_id in(2154, 2156, 2157)
```

When thee are all 4 lagr_id in the list my sql code hangs up. Only server restarting helps :(
Have someone any ideas on how to solve this problem? How to avoid infinity loop in my sql code?
MariaDB version 10.5.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an infinite loop, but you are running out of some resource.

You can improve your query this way:

- I add `DISTINCT` clause in `edges` subquery to avoid duplicated rows.
- I add `CASE` statement in `cte` subquery to avoid set twice the same value (when lagr_id1 = lagr_id2) in `visited` column.
- I replace `UNION ALL` by `UNION` to avoid duplicated rows.

```
WITH
  RECURSIVE 
      edges AS (
          SELECT DISTINCT t1.ltrgr_lagr_id AS lagr_id1, t2.ltrgr_lagr_id AS lagr_id2
          FROM c_logistics_tran_group3 t1 
          INNER JOIN c_logistics_tran_group3 t2 ON t2.ltrgr_ltran_id = t1.ltrgr_ltran_id
          WHERE t1.ltrgr_lagr_id in(2154, 2156, 2157, 2158) 
                AND t2.ltrgr_lagr_id in(2154, 2156, 2157, 2158)
      ),

      cte AS (
          SELECT lagr_id1, lagr_id2, CASE WHEN lagr_id1 = lagr_id2 THEN lagr_id1 ELSE concat(lagr_id1, ',', lagr_id2) END AS visited
          FROM edges
          
          UNION
          
          SELECT c.lagr_id1, e.lagr_id2, concat(c.visited, ',', e.lagr_id2)
          FROM cte c
          INNER JOIN edges e ON e.lagr_id1 = c.lagr_id2
          WHERE NOT find_in_set(e.lagr_id2, c.visited)
      )

SELECT * FROM cte;
```

**The number of rows decreased considerably**, but I think my query can be improve, for example `visited` value '2154,2156,2158,2157' is the same as '2154,2156,2157,2158', because the order of the combination is not important in the result, so the query should discard one of them.